# How to understand "android vitals" information?

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-vitals

I have uploaded the mapping.txt file in the Android Vitals section in the Google Play Console to read the ANR and Crashes in my app but many times I have a hard time understanding the results. Here is an example:

I have 928 of this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.b (AwBrowserProcess.java:10)
  at F5.g (F5.java:27)
  at E5.run (E5.java:2)
  at pt.f (pt.java:11)
  at ot.run (ot.java:2)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7520)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

No idea where to find that in my code.
This is another example with 885 cases:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.b (AwBrowserProcess.java:11)
  at Um.g (Um.java:27)
  at Tm.run (Tm.java:2)
  at bm0.f (bm0.java:11)
  at am0.run (am0.java:2)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7156)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Am I uploading wrongly the mapping.txt file? I can only find one file with that name in my project folders and it is exactly at this location:

> MyAppName\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt

I use that file to upload in the obfuscation file upload of the Android Vitals.